# Improve this Jquery code

Tags: jquery

I have an array of buttons that contain the id's of the buttons. I am then looping through them and adding a click listener. Seems I should be able to do this without the for loop using `.each()`or something, but I could not get it to work with `.each()`

```
var settingScreenButtons = ["btn_1","btn_2","btn_3","btn_4"];

for(var i=0;i<settingScreenButtons.length;i++){
        $("#"+settingScreenButtons[i]).click(function(){
            alert($(this).attr("id"));

        });
    }
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can select multiple elements in one jQuery object and bind to them all at once:

```
$("#btn_1, #btn_2, #btn_3, #btn_4").click(function() {
    alert(this.id);
});
```

Although it's better if you have less event listeners. Say your HTML looked like this:

```
<div id="container">
    <a href="#" id="btn_1" class="btn">Button 1</a>
    <a href="#" id="btn_2" class="btn">Button 2</a>
    <a href="#" id="btn_3" class="btn">Button 3</a>
    <a href="#" id="btn_4" class="btn">Button 4</a>
</div>
```

You can use jQuery's event delegation to solve that more efficiently:

```
$('#container').on('click', '.btn', function() {
    alert(this.id);
});
```

Or, if you really needed that form in your question, you *can* use `each`, but it must be [`$.each`](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.each):

```
$.each(settingScreenButtons, function(index, id) {
    $('#' + id).click(function() {
        alert(this.id);
    });
});
```

Comment: is that this.id or $(this).attr("id") ?

Comment: @Shyju: They're equivalent. The former uses plain DOM attributes; the latter uses jQuery.

Answer (score 0):

Here's another option, starting with the array of id names:

```
var settingScreenButtons = ["btn_1","btn_2","btn_3","btn_4"];

$("#" + settingScreenButtons.join(", #")).click(function() {
    alert(this.id);
});
```